# Trying to Create a Calculator in Java and Got These Errors: How Do I Fix Them?

Tags: java, exception

I wrote this code in Java to create a very simple calculator.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Addition {

static void Addition() {
    Scanner numberOne = new Scanner(System.in);
    float x = numberOne.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("First Number: " + numberOne.nextLine());
    Scanner numberTwo = new Scanner(System.in);
    float y = numberTwo.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Second Number: " + numberTwo.nextLine());
    float sum = x + y;
    System.out.println(sum);    
    }
}

public class Subtraction {

static void Subtraction() {
    Scanner numberOne = new Scanner(System.in);
    float x = numberOne.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("First Number: " + numberOne.nextLine());
    Scanner numberTwo = new Scanner(System.in);
    float y = numberTwo.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Second Number: " + numberTwo.nextLine());
    float difference = x - y;
    System.out.println(difference); 
    }
}

public class Multiplication {

static void Multiplication() {
    Scanner numberOne = new Scanner(System.in);
    float x = numberOne.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("First Number: " + numberOne.nextLine());
    Scanner numberTwo = new Scanner(System.in);
    float y = numberTwo.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Second Number: " + numberTwo.nextLine());
    float product = x + y;
    System.out.println(product);    
    }
}

public class Division {

static void Addition() {
    Scanner numberOne = new Scanner(System.in);
    float x = numberOne.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("First Number: " + numberOne.nextLine());
    Scanner numberTwo = new Scanner(System.in);
    float y = numberTwo.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Second Number: " + numberTwo.nextLine());
    float quotient = x + y;
    System.out.println(quotient);   
}
}

public class Calculate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Calculator");
    System.out.println("Choose an operation:");
    System.out.println("Addition");
    System.out.println("Subtraction");
    System.out.println("Multiplication");
    System.out.println("Division");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = input.nextLine();
    if(choice.equals("Addition") {
        Addition();
    }
    else if(choice.equals("Subtraction") {
        Subtraction();
    }
    else if(choice.equals("Mutliplication") {
        Mutliplication();
    }
    else if(choice.equals("Division"){
        Division();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("That wasn't a valid input. Please try again.");
    }
}
}
```

However, when I tried to run it, I got this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Syntax error on token ")", ) expected after this token
The method Addition() is undefined for the type Calculate
Syntax error on token ")", ) expected after this token
The method Subtraction() is undefined for the type Calculate
Syntax error on token ")", ) expected after this token
The method Mutliplication() is undefined for the type Calculate
Syntax error on token ")", ) expected after this token
The method Division() is undefined for the type Calculate

at Calculate.main(Calculate.java:14)
```

I'm a beginner in Java and I'm not quite sure what the error message means. Can someone explain to me what it means and how I do fix it?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I made the changes and now the program works. There's just one more thing I want to do. If the user gives an invalid input, I want them to be able to try again, but without repeating the entire question. Like if they give something other than those four choices, I want to them just to be able to answer again and for this to repeat until they answer something that is a valid input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few issues in your code.

Firstly, you don't need a separate class for each method.  Just put all the methods together in the same class.  That way, you won't need to specify a class name when you call each method.

Secondly, you're missing some `)` characters in your `if` statements.  Make sure that each `(` character has a matching `)`.  For example, `if (choice.equals("Addition")) {`.

Thirdly, your multiplication and division methods actually seem to be doing addition.  Use `*` to multiply two numbers, and `/` to divide them.

Fourth, lose some of those calls to `nextLine()` and just print the value you've already retrieved.  So, for example, `System.out.println("First Number: " + numberOne.nextLine());` should be `System.out.println("First Number: " + x);` and similarly many times in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your `Addition` method in your class named `Addition`.

1. `import static Addition.Addtion();`
2. Change `Addition()` to `Addition.Addition()`.

You then need to do the same for your other methods. You also are missing a `)` on each of your `choise` tests.

```
if(choice.equals("Addition")) { // <-- count the open and close parens.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Calculate class body, you aren't properly closing your if-statement headers.

```
if(choice.equals("Addition") {
```

should be

```
if(choice.equals("Addition")) { // notice the second closing parenthesee
```

You have to put a closing parenthesee for every open one you have.

Answer (score 0):

You had a syntax error where you didn't add the necessary close parenthesis for the if statements.

```
if(choice.equals("Addition") <---- missing parenthesis {
    Addition();
}
```

**Solution**

```
if(choice.equals("Addition")) {
    Addition();
}
else if(choice.equals("Subtraction")) {
    Subtraction();
}
else if(choice.equals("Mutliplication")) {
    Mutliplication();
}
else if(choice.equals("Division")){
    Division();
}
else {
    System.out.println("That wasn't a valid input. Please try again.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are placing the methods like addition and subtraction in their own classes so Main doesn't know how to call them.

I would say scrap the public classes preceding each math method.  Also change your

```
System.out.println("Second Number: " + numberTwo.nextLine());
```

to something like:

```
System.out.println("Second Number: " + y);
```

If you want it to actually spit out the respective numbers.